# Having two vents on a laptop instead of one

Tags: laptop, fan, thinkpad

On my levono thinkpad sl410 there are two vents. The laptop has two CPUs - does that mean that each fan has its own vents?

[image: picture of laptop]

Comment: There could be two vents purely because the designer thought it would look sexier.  There could be two vents because the box tends to catch fire with only one.  There's no correlation between number of vents and number of processors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system does not have two physical CPUs.  As you mention two CPUs, it's likely got a Core 2 Duo, which is a single piece of silicon that has two CPUs in it, aka a dual-core processor.

See [Multi-core processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-core) on Wikipedia for more details.

Most likely, both vents are connected to the same fan and are to optimize airflow (maybe one flows in and the other flows out).